# Connect PySide to a signal using QSignalMapper and an instance method

Tags: python, qt, pyside, signals-slots

I have a small app with a table. This table has some data and a button on each row. These buttons should allow the user to remove corresponding row data. I'm trying to implement it via the `clicked` button signal, but I need to pass the row number, so I tried using `QSignalMapper`, as shown in the excerpt below

```
btnRemoveItem = QPushButton()
btnRemoveItem.clicked.connect(self.removeItem)
self.mapper = QSignalMapper(self)
self.connect(btnRemoveItem, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.mapper,
        QtCore.SLOT("map()"))
self.mapper.setMapping(btnRemoveItem, nextRow)
self.connect(self.mapper, QtCore.SIGNAL("mapped(int)"), self.removeItem(),
        QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked(int)"))
```

Problem is, my `removeItem(self, index)` method is an instance method (because my table belongs to a specific class) and I'm having trouble mapping it in a way I can pass `self` along with `index`.

Currently, my code fails with the following error:

```
TypeError: removeItem() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Is there a way to make this work correctly? Or is it impossible to map instance methods with `QSignalMapper` in PySide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your code in PyQt but I'm not fully aware of the differences between Pyside and PyQt so my answer is more of a guess.
Try to remove the second line of your code and replace the last one with:

```
self.mapper.mapped.connect(self.removeItem)
```

Answer (score 3):

In the last line of your code, in the `connect` method, I believe you have a typo in your code

```
self.connect(self.mapper, QtCore.SIGNAL("mapped(int)"), self.removeItem(), 
    QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked(int)"))
```

should be

```
self.connect(self.mapper, QtCore.SIGNAL("mapped(int)"), self.removeItem,
    QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked(int)"))
```

Having `self.removeItem()` in the connect method will actually try to call the `self.removeItem method` rather than providing the subsystem an address to connect the function

As finmor suggests, you should look at [new syntax signals and slots](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Signals_and_Slots_in_PySide) as they will dramatically help to clarify your code and make it more Pythonic.